# java installed from android studio but it's not accessible

Tags: java, android-studio, ubuntu, java-17

i installed android studio on my Ubuntu and it came with java11, then i installed java  from it and set $JAVA_HOME with this 2 commands:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/<user>/.jdks/openjdk-17.0.2/ /*location where did android studio installed java17*/
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

echo $JAVA_HOME dose return the given location
```

then typed `bash` into terminal /**as followed in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459900/how-to-find-my-current-java-home-in-ubuntu)**/

then `java --version` return :

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.13+8-0ubuntu1~20.04, or
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.7+5-0ubuntu1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-16-jre-headless  # version 16.0.1+9-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.1+12-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
```

i restarted the pc and it's still the same output.

still when coding with android studio everything is working properly

Comment: Is there a `/home/<user>/.jdks/openjdk-17.0.2/bin/java` and is it an executable file? What happens if you try to run `/home/<user>/.jdks/openjdk-17.0.2/bin/java --version`?

Comment: yes there is an excutable file called java in /home/<user>/.jdks/openjdk-17.0.2/bin/
and runing /home/<user>/.jdks/openjdk-17.0.2/bin/java --version dose show the java version

Comment: Sounds like a different executable named `java` is in your path. Try `type java`

Comment: bash: type: java: not found

Comment: You may verify the `PATH` variable using `echo $PATH`. To minimize potential problems, use `PATH="$PATH:/home/<user>/.jdks/openjdk-17.0.2/bin/"` to set the path. Note that java itself doesn’t care about the `JAVA_HOME` variable. All it takes, is getting to run the executable contained in the JDK, whether via `PATH` or an `alias` or directly using `/path/to/java` doesn’t matter.